# Where does George Weah stand on the political spectrum? Is he progressive or conservative?

Tags: president, political-spectrum, liberia

Where does George Weah stand on the political spectrum? Is he progressive or conservative?
I know his party (CDC) is centre-right, is he?

Comment: Words like "progressive", "conservative", "left" and "right" mean different things to different people. It would help if you were to re-frame your question to ask about specific views.

Answer (score 1):

George Weah has represented the CDC in the Liberian Senate since 2014.  He has consistently supported CDC policies (as would be expected for the chairman of the party) His political opinions can be summarised as being entirely aligned with the party that he leads: He is generally to the right of President Sirleaf.